# How to save and reload iptables permanently in openSUSE?

Tags: linux, iptables, opensuse

I was trying to save iptable configuration and someone suggested me `iptables-save` which wasn't convencing for me. I logged in and tried `/etc/init.d/iptables save` and `service` command, none worked and didn't find any online reference.

```
-bash-4.2# iptables --version   
iptables v1.4.19.1
-bash-4.2# 

 -bash-4.2# uname  -a
Linux server 2.6.32-042stab120.6 #1 SMP Thu Oct 27 16:59:03 MSK 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
-bash-4.2#

-bash-4.2# cat /etc/SuSE-brand 
BasedOnopenSUSE
VERSION = 13.1
-bash-4.2#
```

**EDIT:** Error message I am getting when tried `/etc/init.d/iptables save` and `service iptables save`

```
 server:~ # /etc/init.d/iptables save; cat /etc/os-release | grep VER
    -bash: /etc/init.d/iptables: No such file or directory
    VERSION="13.1 (Bottle)"
    VERSION_ID="13.1"
server:~ # service iptables save
service: no such service iptables
server:~ #
```

What is the command in suse to reload iptables configuration in openSUSE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in openSUSE the iptables are not designed to be manipulated directly. There is no way to store the current state in a way you can reload it later.

The firewall settings are stored in `/etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2`. You can either edit this file directly or use YaST to configure it. After changing the file you have to run `/sbin/SuSEfirewall2` or `service SuSEfirewall2 start` to load the changes.

See the documentation for details on the configuration:

- https://en.opensuse.org/SuSEfirewall2
- `/usr/share/doc/packages/SuSEfirewall2/`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SuSE but on CentOS the `service iptables save` command uses `iptables-save` to (eventually) write the filrewall state to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. You may want to load the script into your favourite text editor - it's generally quite readable.

When you run `service iptables start`, firewall stare is loaded from `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.

If you want to reload the firewall state then try `service iptables reload` or even `service iptables restart`

Comment: I need answer specifically for suse

Comment: Go and read the script then, you'll likely find that at most the destination file is different.

Comment: @istheEnglishway while this is true for most distributions, it is different with SuSE. See for yourself: https://github.com/openSUSE/susefirewall2/blob/master/SuSEfirewall2

Comment: @GeraldSchneider so in that case the op should be getting an error message when running `/etc/init.d/iptables save` that they are not discolsing.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider See, now it all becomes clear ... cluelessness rules.